# What is the easiest way to save file from Google Dataflow to Google Storage?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've got my pipeline up and running, but I need to save a number to a file, which will allow me to come back to previous processing in case something goes wrong ( or when I want to deploy new version of pipeline, and I cannot use the update-pipeline feature ).

I was trying to add libraries from google-cloud-storage, but there are errors in Runtime (it does not find some classes from google-cloud-core even when I have all dependencies up to date ). There need to be a simple way, just to save ( and then read ) a file. I will be grateful for some snippet or link.

Comment: Just write to GCS directly from your pipeline using `TextIO`

Comment: I you are looking for a way to track metadata as a layer outside of the job itself, it would be ideal if you could just lean on the cloud storage drivers like you said.  I would recommend putting the cloud storage dependencies 1st in your pom file and maybe giving it another go? (we have successfully used cloud storage directly, alongside dataflow 1.x without any problems).

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is too late to answer this :D. But perhaps can help other people. If you are encountering dependency hell because of using different GCP components, use https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-bom. They have created a pom file that keeps track of all the compatible versions in different components.

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck in dependency hell, and must do this step from within dataflow, then I would recommend looking at side-inputs and outputs...and then pairing that with some simple TextIO operations.